# Manually add a program to the File and Folders access list

Tags: security, filesystem, big-sur

I've just installed [Xournal++](https://github.com/xournalpp/xournalpp) on my MacBook Pro running Big Sur. Most things work fine, but it can't access the Desktop, Documents or Downloads. Usually, programs request permission and one gets a pop-up, then they appear under Files and Folders in Security. However, that doesn't happen for Xournal++ so I can't authorise it. How do I add it to the list manually?

Comment: Have you tried adding the program to allow full disk access in System Preferences? Go to `System Preferences`>`Security & Privacy`> `Full Disc Access` or `Files and Folders` and add your program there?

Comment: @AVelj That's exactly what I want to do, but I need to add the program to the list in the first place: it doesn't automatically ask for permission so doesn't even appear. There must be a way to add it: I just need to know how.